# I cannot connect to my VM Instance all of a sudden

Tags: virtual-machines, remote-desktop, connection

I have a Google Cloud VM Instance which had been working perfectly up until today. I have tried to log onto it all day but it won't connect through my phone or laptop. I haven't changed any settings or passwords or anything that might affect it. It was literally working yesterday but not today for some reason. I even pinged the IP addy and it came back all good.

I get this error message:

"This computer can't connect to the remote computer. Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator".

Is anyone able to help me get connected again?

Thanks in Advance
Rob

Comment: Ping only shows that the server (or rather, a device with this address) responds to ICMP echo requests. You tag the question with "remote desktop", which indicates Windows. Correct? Can you use the IP address with your remote desktop client? Can you connect via the server's console? Is there a way to restart that server?

Comment: Hi berndbausch, thanks for replying. Yes I am accessing the VM from my windows 8.1 laptop. I use remote desktop connection to do it and it has never had any troubles connecting previously. I use the IP addy and the username of the VM to connect. I don't understand how to connect via the server's console and I'm not sure how to restart the server. I will search for how to do these though, thanks.

Comment: I also use a mobile phone app called Microsoft Remote Desktop to access the VM from my phone. This cannot connect either.

Comment: You may be interested in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance and https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp. As to the console, I am not sure if there is such a thing for GCP Windows instances, so please disregard that comment of mine.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies berndbausch. Stopping and re-starting the instance worked. I can now log back into the server. Much appreciated 